# How can I avoid drawer touching status bar? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, expo

im using drawer, but i cant see in the documentation where I can set the height of the drawer, because its touching the status bar and I want it below of it:

problem:

[image]

what I want:

[image]

as you can see in the second image the drawer is below of the status bar, how can do it? it has a parameter that is `contentComponents` but this is only for the icons, not for the entire drawer

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of research I think the best way to achieve this is to put your content inside SafeAreaView:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}>
 <Text>Your Content</Text>
</SafeAreaView>
```

[Without SafeAreaView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDDAt.png)

[With SafeAreView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ7pB.png)